# Remove cookie is not deleting cookie

Tags: cookies, quasar

i am trying to delete cookies in quasar using below command

```
Cookies.remove('user', options)
```

This command is just clearing the cookie value instead of deleting the cookie. Is there a different command to delete cookies?

Answer (score 1):

Quasar doc :

> When a cookie was previously set with specific path and/or domain then
> it can be successfully removed only if the same attributes are passed
> in to remove() through the options parameter.

To remove it, use:

````
// outside of a Vue file
import { Cookies } from 'quasar'

Cookies.remove('cookie_name')

// if cookie was set with specific options like path and/or domain
// then you need to also supply them when removing:
Cookies.remove('cookie_name', options)```
````